# OAuth with non-interactive, service accounts

Tags: oauth-2.0

Is the authorization code grant type only for interactive accounts? I'm working with an API that does not appear to support client credentials grant and unless I fallback to basic auth (user:token) I do not know how we would make this work for a user that (to us) is a service account.

The piece I am struggling with is the return of the authorization code. If I hit the generated URL to request the auth code I receive a dialog asking me to allow/validate access and by accepting I am returned to the redirect_uri with the code param. This required human interaction which in our scenario we would not have. Auth codes are not supposed to be long lived so I cannot just save this for future use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first piece, getting an authorization code, needs to be done manually by a human.

The authorization code is short-lived so you wouldn't want to store the auth code for use later.

Thankfully, you can trade in that authorization code for an access token and refresh token. Though the access token expires, usually around an hour, the refresh token often remains active for an extended amount of time (this is can vary by API). The API I am working with at the moment does not document when it expires, it may not expire ever.

We'll just note that if the refresh code ever fails/expires then we should manually go to the authorization URL to get a new auth code which we can trade in for a *new* access token and refresh token. We'll keep the refresh token stored securely and will plug in the refresh token in our automation. The automation will not make `authorization_code` grant type calls  (that part we'll still keep manual) and will only make `refresh_token` grant type calls (those can be automated) as well as the calls to do the actual work with the API once we have a fresh, valid access token.